# C# AutoMapper map array of strings into List of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, list, automapper

Hello I'm trying to map array of strings from one class to another structure, Kinda new with AutoMapper.

It should look like this : SourceClass.Numbers -> new DestClass.ListClass { Numbers }

```
    public class SourceClass
    {
        public string[] Numbers;
    }

    public class DestClass
    {
        public List<ListClass> ListOfNumbers;
    }

    public class ListClass
    {
        public string Number;
    }

   cfg.CreateMap<ETOLL_212, Etoll212Request>().ForMember(x => x.ListOfNumbers, y => y.Ignore())
                                              .AfterMap((src, dest) =>
                                              {
                                                        dest.ListOfNumbers.AddRange(src.Numbers.ToList()
                                                            .Select(x =>
                                                            {
                                                                new DestClass{ Number = x.ToString() };
                                                            }).ToList());
                                              });
```

Comment: You've left some of the original class names in your example, do you need to edit it?

Answer (score 0):

Because the source and destination property names don't match, you need to define an explicit mapping for those:

```
cfg.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestClass>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.ListOfNumbers,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Numbers));
```

Additionally, because the item types don't match, you need another mapping to be defined:

```
cfg.CreateMap<string, ListClass>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Number,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
```

Because `ListOfNumbers`, and `Numbers` are both collection types, AutoMapper can use the above mappings to map each item: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html

Comment: Works perfect, Thank you very much !